# VS2013 Find replace code and the empty line with it

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've been looking all over and can not find a way to find/replace a search term, and also remove the line with it. Here is an example of what I would like

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Unit")]
public void Test()
{
}
```

To

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
}
```

But instead (trying to replace the term with empty), I am getting this, which **does** make sense, but not what I desire.

```
[TestMethod]

public void Test()
{
}
```

How can I remove the line with it?

Comment: Can't you add the newline symbol to your search?? - Then the replace should do the trick,, no?

Comment: such as `[TestCategory("Unit")]\n`? Tried. No dice

Comment: AND what are you replacing it with?, just `""`, right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions in VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx). The following will match the two lines

Search: `\[TestMethod\]\r?\n\ *\[TestCategory\("Unit"\)\]`

Replace: `[TestMethod]`

Should do what you want. Note you have to escape the brackets in your search string with `\`

Answer (score 0):

you need to brain visual studio 2013, select [TestCategory("Unit")] +
 the end of [TestMethod]<----here and copy it in FindandReplace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I generally use Sublime Text

1. copy code from VS to sublime
2. select the part you want to replace
3. press <kbd>ALT+F3</kbd> which will select all instances of that text
4. press backspace all you like until you get what you want.
5. copy and paste back yo VS.
6. (optional) pray god for Sublime Text.

Comment: My concern is that I have hundreds of cs files, and wish to find/replace across an entire solution, also containing many products. Trying to avoid as much labor as possible